# Datepicker Ajax break

Tags: asp.net, ajax, datepicker, actionresult

I have a jQuery datepicker that works except when the Ajax in updateTable is done. 
The numbers in the calendar cells disappear and selection of cells is prevented. This occurs regardless of what is in updateTable's result. What is the problem?

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        initDatepicker();

        $("#btn").live('click', function (event) {

              $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Add")',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (result) {
                        updateTable();
                }
            });
        });

  });

  function initDatepicker () {               
      $('.datepicker').datepicker();   
  };


  function updateTable() {          
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateTable")',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                $("#table").append(result);
            },
        });
    };

</script>

</head>

<body>
      <div>
        @RenderBody()
      </div>

      <div id="table">
      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must re-init the date picker after the Update of your Ajax, because you change the DOM struct and the previous is not longer valid. So call again the `initDatepicker();` after you update the table as:

```
 function updateTable() {          
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateTable")',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                $("#table").append(result);
                // here call again the init
                initDatepicker();    
            },
        });
    };
```

Comment: @Mixel work a little with your code (if you understand it), do not wait from me to fix it, or give me a url to check it in full. The answer "it has no effect" is gives me no clue except that you do not know nothing at all about.